# Errno 86 Bad CPU type in executable in spyder 5 python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, spyder, errno

I use selenium for web scraping and the code that uses it has been working fine for over a year. Suddenly, last week, it stopped working. Chrome had just upgraded to 112, so I upgraded my chromedriver to the correct version of 112 as well. Then I started getting this error: [Errno 86] Bad CPU type in executable: '/Users/harrisonray/Desktop/Chromedriver112/chromedriver112'. I tried downloading an older version of chrome (104) and the accompanying chromedriver, but I continued to get the same error. I'm still pretty new at all of this. Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to solve this issue? I am currently on macOS Ventura 13.3.1. Using anaconda with python 5.3.3.

I tried changing from bash to zsh in my terminal. I tried updating my anaconda, spyder, and macOS and they are all up to date. I tried going back to earlier versions of chrome with the accompanying webdriver. But nothing will get rid of tis error.

Comment: How did you update your chromedriver? Are you entirely sure you are using one that matches your operating system and CPU architecture?